# module.export not changing variable for other file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, socket.io

I have two arrays of objects that I am exporting at the end of `server.js` with `module.exports` which will be used in another file to display scores, `scores.js`. My problem occurs when I try and reset these arrays when a new games begins and for some reason some data seems to not update in `scores.js` whilst others do.

I have been researching and think it has something to do with the way javascript saves objects and I have been trying different ways of deep/shallow cloning however nothing seems to work.

More specifically, there is a property in one of the arrays of objects called `playersChoosing` which is also an array and is the one that seems not to change even if I completely set the array of objects to an empty one in the `server.js` file.

Note: This is my first time properly using node.js so could definitely be missing something very basic. Any help is appreciated!

These are examples of the two objects:

```
Current player definitions [
  { definition: 'maiming; mutilation', playersChoosing: [ 'player4' ] },
  {
    definition: 'blah blah',
    id: 'vIe_bxsTjg4OzFdJAAAB',
    playersChoosing: [],
    choseCorrect: false
  },
  {
    definition: 'whatever',
    id: 'b7lJloolPhLGdrrnAAAD',
    playersChoosing: [ 'player1', 'player2', 'player3' ],
    choseCorrect: true
  },
  {
    definition: 'foo',
    id: 'o7rTbhVp8WllpLTwAAAF',
    playersChoosing: [],
    choseCorrect: false
  },
  {
    definition: 'bar',
    id: 'lMnqOsIzdfQMBWPVAAAH',
    playersChoosing: [],
    choseCorrect: false
  }
]
```

```
Game connections [
  {
    id: 'vIe_bxsTjg4OzFdJAAAB',
    nickname: 'player1',
    ready: true,
    score: 2
  },
  {
    id: 'b7lJloolPhLGdrrnAAAD',
    nickname: 'player2',
    ready: true,
    score: 4
  },
  {
    id: 'o7rTbhVp8WllpLTwAAAF',
    nickname: 'player3',
    ready: true,
    score: 1
  },
  {
    id: 'lMnqOsIzdfQMBWPVAAAH',
    nickname: 'player4',
    ready: true,
    score: 1
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where the arrays are being export and "reset"? The exports hold a reference to the original array, so if you are doing something like  `definitions = []` that just assigns a new array.

Comment: If you are exporting the arrays directly, you might want to look at exporting helper functions or a class to manage the array instead.

Comment: @Matt yeh I set the definitions = [] is their a better way to do this?

Comment: I’ll have a look at helper functions

Comment: Yeh sweet helper functions were the way to go @Matt, feel free to post an answer and Ill mark it as accepted. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A contrived example of exporting functions that manage data housed in the singleton module, rather than the data itself.

```
let definitions = [
  { 1: 'a' },
  { 2: 'b' },
  { 3: 'c' },
]

export function clearDefinitions(){
  definitions.length = 0
  return true
}

export function currentDefinitions(){
  return definitions // internal array
  return definitions.slice() // or copy of internal array
}

export function addDefinition(obj){
  const cloned_obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) // copy of arg
  definitions.push(cloned_obj)
  return true
}
```

Then there are data structures like a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which already do all the helpers for you. (`.clear` `.get` `.set` `.entries`) that will act upon itself

```
export const definitions = new Map()
```

Which can be extended

```
export class NedMap extends Map {
  gameTransform(obj) {
    // do things
    this.set(obj.id, obj)
    return this
  }
}

export const definitions = new NedMap()
```

Depending on how much you want to protect the modules data, something like [Immutable](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js) might be handy to cover more of the edge cases of handling shared data in JS and the unexpected modifications that can come from that sharing.

For example, in the initial array code, Even though a copy of the `definitions` array is returned from `slice` the objects inside the array still reference the same original objects.

Something outside the module setting `definitions.1 = 'argh'` still modifies the shared object due to that reference to the original modules object. That can be useful in cases, or a pain in others.

Comment: Yeh thanks for the clarification, I was able to get around it by using a basic helper function. I’ll make sure to have a look into all of the strategies above. Cheers

Comment: Also for the referencing problems I was able to use the lodash.clonedeep methods for a cleaner way to deep clone the objects

Answer (score 0):

let's take a look at this demo.I write three .js file something like:

```js
// values.js
module.exports = {
   name: 'jack',
   score: [34]
}
```

```js
// container.js
const values = require('./values')
values.score = []
module.exports = {
   name: 'peter',
   container: values
}
```

```js
// main.js
const values = require('./values')
const p = require('./container')
console.log('values: ', values)
console.log('p: ', p.container)
```

Ok, you run `node main.js`;
you find that values and p is same.
`module.exports` just export an object, and in main.js and container.js, we share the reference of that object `values`.You change `values` in container.js, and the changes will be seen in main.js `values`.
Maybe you're failed to share the reference, and then you cannot find the changes.

Comment: Ok I’ll have a look to see, thanks